# Adding depth/dimension to an icon font?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fonts, font-face, css

I would like to put a border, i.e., give some depth or dimension, around an icon but it doesn't look like CSS's `text-shadow` property is what I should be using.

I'm using the [FontAwesome icon collection](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/) which is used along with [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/).

Below is a link to a JSFiddle demo (whose HTML and CSS is also shown below) with up and down arrows which I would like to look more textured:

http://jsfiddle.net/trpeters1/PcmNC/14/

HTML:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

<ul class='well'>  
   <li class='alignCenter'> 
     <i class='icon-caret-up icon-green icon-4x'></i>
   </li>
   <li class='voteTots alignCenter' >3</li>            
   <li class='alignCenter'> 
     <i class=' icon-caret-down icon-gray icon-4x'></i>           
   </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  font-size:200%; /* resets the page font size */
}
ul li.alignCenter{
  margin:auto;
  width:50%;
  text-align:center;
}
.icon-green{
  color:#58A279;    
}
.icon-gray{
  color:gray;   
}
.voteTots{
  font-size:60px;
  color:#666;
}
```

Comment: You can't put shadows *inside* text, just outside. There's no CSS effect for text that involves doing what you can do with "internal" box-shadow effects, I don't think. It'd be really nice if there were.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure text shadow isn't what you want?

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/PcmNC/17/

Uses

```
.shadow {
text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #666; /* horizontal vertical blur colour */
}
```

Comment: That does work, its just not very asthetically pleasing. That is why I'm wondering if something besides `text-shadow` would produce a better effect. I'd rather have it look like a raised button.

Comment: I'm assuming you've ruled out the look of any of the default bootstrap buttons. Other than that, I suppose you could make a graphic of your button (less the arrow head) and include it as a bacground, then use CSS to scale the width and height to 100%. Seems a bit convoluted though and it's counter to the reason for using an icon font in the first place. Probably easier to use a plain grapic button. I'm interested to see if there are any other suggestions.